# Same databses for ruby and django

Tags: django, ruby

I have same database for ruby and django.
Ruby stores user data using bcrypt algorithm(i.e using devise gem):
ex : `$2a$10$5JhrmU73vXEJWyoBQqYaKeM6a5KwxTfTrfARJmyyl.E8Tir3Q0nlG`

But to authenticate same user in django,my django bcrypt algorithm should also output same text that is:
`$2a$10$5JhrmU73vXEJWyoBQqYaKeM6a5KwxTfTrfARJmyyl.E8Tir3Q0nlG`.

How to do this?

It's exactly opposite of this question:
[Migrate django users to rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061001/migrate-django-users-to-rails)

Answer (score 0):

A bcrypt hash contains a salt. In order to verify whether a given password matches a given hash, you need to use the same salt in the calculation as in the given bcrypt hash.

Since the bcrypt format is standardized, this is abstracted by most authentication libraries ao that you don't need to handle this on your own. Django supports bcrypt [out of the box](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/passwords/#using-bcrypt-with-django).

Please refer to the above linked documentation. In short, you can

1. Install bcrypt in your Django environment with `python -m pip install django[bcrypt]`
2. Modify your [`PASSWORD_HASHERS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-PASSWORD_HASHERS) setting to include `'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptSHA256PasswordHasher'`, e.g.

   ```
   PASSWORD_HASHERS = [
       'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptSHA256PasswordHasher',
       'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2PasswordHasher',
       'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2SHA1PasswordHasher',
       'django.contrib.auth.hashers.Argon2PasswordHasher',
   ]
   ```